# How to wrap text in flalign

Tags: align

not a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147429/how-to-wrap-text-with-flalign) because I want to keep the equation numbering, so a tabular won't do (I think).

I am using flalign to typeset philosophical arguments. I also want to use hyperref to be able to hotlink back to the individual lines of the argument later in the document. This works fine until I have a sentence that needs to be wrapped to the next line.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
&& \text{This is premise 1.} && \text{(Premise)} \label{premise1} \\
&& \text{This is premise 2. What happens when the text goes over the line though? } && \text{(From \autoref{premise1})}\label{premise2}
\end{flalign}

Obviously \autoref{premise2} follows from \autoref{premise1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: why use flalign at all??? it seems very strange to use a math alignment and then force it to be text in every cell, why not use a text alignment (or a list, which looks more suitable)?

Comment: Because I'll end up with 50 or 60 different lines and I want to be able to autoref them.

Comment: yes I you want automatic numbering/references but why the math? I couldn't tell from the example where the "long" text is in your real case or whether both fields need to allow long text.

Comment: I think a theorem-like structure would be better from a conceptual point point of view, and it allows for numbering and referencing.

Comment: Oh, sometimes the lines will need modal logic symbols, sometimes they need to just be plain text where the symbolism is overkill. ideally both fields would have to allow long text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop my suggestion of using a theorem-like structure, using `ntheorem` and `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[thref, hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{prem}{Premise}
\begin{document}

\begin{prem}\label{prem1}
  This is the text of premise 1. A very promising premise
\end{prem}

\begin{prem}\label{prem2}
  This is premise 2. What happens when the text goes over the line though? \\
  \footnotesize(from \cref{prem1}).
\end{prem}
Obviously \cref{prem2} follows from \cref{prem1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `\parbox`:

[image]

### Notes:

- As others have stated, this is *not* a recommended approach. You may want to post a new question asking for suggestions on exactly the desired out along with the constraints that you have. I am sure there are many better ways to do this.

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
&& \text{This is premise 1.} && \text{(Premise)} \label{premise1} \\
&& \parbox[t]{0.6\linewidth}{This is premise 2. What happens when the text goes over the line though? } && \text{(From \autoref{premise1})}\label{premise2}
\end{flalign}

Obviously \autoref{premise2} follows from \autoref{premise1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this a lot, but now the first line of (2) isn't aligned with the equation tag. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You can, but I wouldn't:-) using fleqn is pretty odd anyway, but putting a fixed size parbox in it is doubly weird as you don't need to align fixed size boxes (they are fixed width anyway) and you don't need them to be in math:-) (It is though the answer to the question asked, of how to wrap text in a flalign)

Comment: @shane: See updated solution.

Comment: @shane -- from your comment, it sounds like you have the equation numbers on the right.  (`amsart` default is on the left, but you didn't specify `[reqno]`.)  where *do* you want them -- left or right?

Comment: Adding to @barbarabeeton's remark, this is very depending on the fact that `amsart` uses `leqno` and will dramatically break if the journal where the paper is submitted prefers `reqno`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want math at all.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{longtable,array,hyperref}


\makeatletter
\newcounter{premise}
\newcommand\premiseautorefname{premise}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{longtable}{@{\stepcounter{premise}(\thepremise) }
                 >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9cm}
                 >{\addtocounter{premise}{-1}\refstepcounter{premise}\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}
This is premise 1. &(Premise) \label{premise1} \\
This is premise 2. What happens when the text goes over the line though? &
From \autoref{premise1}\label{premise2}
\end{longtable}

Obviously \autoref{premise2} follows from \autoref{premise1}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a text alignment but as I noted in the initial comment a list structure (as used by theorems) is more suitable really, so the I'm glad to see you accepted Bernards answer (even though it dropped the three column layout that flalign was using)

Comment: Ah, this is very nice. This looks more like what I pictured in my head, but I accepted Bernard's answer because probably the right answer here is to use amsthm to define a new environment. Thanks for your help though!